# How do i get Location String as path using c#?

Tags: c#, process, location, registry, key-value

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KXds.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KXds.png

I want to open Location String in Explorer.exe

```
try
{
    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wilcom\Wilcom EmbroideryStudio\4.2H"))
    {
        if (key != null)
        {
            Object o = key.GetValue("Location");
            if (o != null)
            {
                Version version = new Version(o as String);  //"as" because it's REG_SZ...otherwise ToString() might be safe(r)
                Process.Start(key.GetValue("Location").ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)  //just for demonstration...it's always best to handle specific exceptions
{
    //react appropriately
}
```

It's not working. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

`Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select," + o.ToString());`

This opens File Explorer with the location set as indicated using command-line arguments.

See [Explorer.exe - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/explorer.html)

Comment: Please provide explanation as why this is a solution along with your code.

Comment: OP hadn't done much effort to lookup command line for explorer.exe, and I thought it was immediately obvious what I meant. Have edited.